# Pila de datos imprime null al final

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, pilas

Tengo una pila llamada *pilaBoletos* la cual almacena una cantidad de boletos comprados. La idea es que esta pila debe imprimirse tanto en consola (*output*) como en un *JOptionPane*. A pesar de que si imprime la pila, pasa que al final de la lista de elementos agrega un *null*, porque el *aux.setAbajo* esta apuntado a *null* al final del la pila. Necesito ayuda para que no imprima ese *null* al final, por favor.

**La clase PilaBoletos:**

```
public class PilaBoletos {

    private NodoPilaBoletos top;

    public void push(NodoPilaBoletos ElementoNuevo) {
        ElementoNuevo.setAbajo(top);
        top = ElementoNuevo;
    }

    public NodoPilaBoletos pop() {
        NodoPilaBoletos aux = top;
        if (PilaVacia()) {
            System.out.println("No hay elementos en la pila");
        } else {
            top = top.getAbajo();
            aux.setAbajo(null);
        }
        return aux;
    }

    public boolean PilaVacia() {
        if (top == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void listar() {
        NodoPilaBoletos aux = top;
        // Recorre la pila hasta el ultimo nodo.
        while (aux != null) {
            System.out.println("|\t" + "Boleto A" + aux.getValor() + "\t|");
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
            aux = aux.getAbajo();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + top;
    }
}
```

**La clase NodoPilaBoletos:**

```
public class NodoPilaBoletos {

    private int valor;
    private NodoPilaBoletos abajo;

    public NodoPilaBoletos(int valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    NodoPilaBoletos() {
        
    }

    public int getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(int valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public NodoPilaBoletos getAbajo() {        
       return abajo; 
    }

    public void setAbajo(NodoPilaBoletos abajo) {
        this.abajo = abajo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A" + valor + ",  " + abajo + "\n";
    } 
}
```

link para descarga codigo completo (netbeans) [googleDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ATbVQw3msJ2Q3UCal6Lnh2p2WILzEzqL/view?usp=sharing)

El main tiene un menu, la opcion donde se usa la pila es en "Comprar Boletos" y se imprime en la linea de codigo #180.

Gracias,

Comment: Y si añades un `if (aux.getValor() != null)` antes de imprimir?? Con todo lo que has hecho, comprobar que no sea null antes de imprimir me parece demasiado fácil....

Comment: @Benito-B me puedes aconsejar como? He estado modificando el método donde se imprime como me lo has indicado, aun agregando aux.getAbajo().getValor(), sin embargo, no me cambia el resultado.